# Spring Web Security configuration for API routes issue

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-rest

I have Spring application with REST API.

In my WebSecurityConfig I have configuration of access to routes.

These are my main routes:

- /api/auth/login - login purposes
- /api/admin/** - access only for admin with role "ADMIN"
- /api/** - access for any authenticated user

I have problem with 2 last ones. Depending on change in my code I have **"/api/admin/**"** route accessible for everyone or anyone (even ADMIN). Is it even possible to achieve or should I change last routes to **"/api/common/**"** (then it is working fine)?

Here's part of my code:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    AjaxLoginFilter ajaxLoginFilter = ajaxLoginFilter();

    http
            .cors()
            .and()

            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.authenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()

            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/login").permitAll()
            .and()

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(ajaxLoginFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**")
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(ajaxLoginFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenAuthenticationFilterAdmin(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

protected JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter jwtTokenAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    List<String> pathsToSkip = Arrays.asList("/api/auth/login", "/api/admin/**");
    SkipPathRequestMatcher matcher = new SkipPathRequestMatcher(pathsToSkip, "/api/**");
    JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter filter
            = new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(failureHandler, tokenExtractor, matcher);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    return filter;
}

protected JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter jwtTokenAuthenticationFilterAdmin() throws Exception {
    List<String> pathsToSkip = Arrays.asList("/api/auth/login", "/api/**");
    SkipPathRequestMatcher matcher = new SkipPathRequestMatcher(pathsToSkip, "/api/admin/**");
    JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter filter
            = new JwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(failureHandler, tokenExtractor, matcher);
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);
    return filter;
}
```

In code above  **"/api/admin/**"** is not accessible to anyone. If I remove **"/api/**"** from **pathsToSkip** List in method **jwtTokenAuthenticationFilterAdmin()** with filter to admin then it is accessible to everyone.

So the question is - can I fix it or I should just change routes accessible to any authenticated user from **"/api/**"** to **"/api/common/**"**?

Comment: `.authorizeRequests()` shouldn't be called multiple times.

Comment: @boristheSpider so how should I do it?

Comment: I would suggest reading [the tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/). Explaining how the default `SecurityMetadataSource` works is beyond the scope of this site.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've read it but there are only simple routes and I have problem with more sophisticated routes, also user Roles and only REST API without any views (like formLogin in tutorial).

Comment: Your "routes" are extremely simple, and almost identical to the tutorial. You have a login area with `permitAll`, a user area that requires authentication and an `admin` area that requires a role. I would suggest reading the tutorial much more carefully if you cannot see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `authorizeRequests()` repeatedly i.e.:

```
        ...

        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/auth/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(ajaxLoginFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

        ...
```

Comment: thank you, I thought I have to add filters to every authenticated router seperately and I couldn't figure out how to do that with only one authorizeRequests() call. At first I also had wrong order /api/admin/** was after /api/**

Comment: @user3626048 looking at the [code for `DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/access/intercept/DefaultFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java) is quite informative. It basically is a `LinkedHashMap` of `RequestMatcher` where each `RequestMatcher` is checked against the current `HttpServletRequest` and the first one that matches is used. That is the magic of open source code; something not working - have a nose around and see why!